# Android stuck in downloading mode

Tags: battery, charging, downloading, samsung-galaxy-s-4

So what happened is that my mobile (Galaxy S4 - GT-9500) ran out of charge.

When I plugged in the charger and tried to turn it on, it went directly to what I think is the recovery mode (Android logo with text "Downloading...Don't turn off target")

I turned it off, pulled off the battery and tried to turn it on again nothing happens.

I tried different solution but nothing happens, just the black screen Here is what I tried so far:

1- Home + on/off button + volume up

2- Home + on/off button + volume down

3- plug it in the PC for hours and then along press on the on/off button

Any other suggestions ?

Comment: Leaving the battery out for a little longer (e.g. 1 minute) might be worth a try. Also check that there's no "stuck button" which might causing this (unlikely, but who knows).

Comment: @Izzy Unfortunately this did not work also.
I even plugged the wall charger in for a long time and nothing happened

Comment: I'm reluctant to suggest the last-ressort: Can you still do a factory-reset? Apart from that (and giving the device to service), I'm out of ideas as well.

Comment: IF you mean the (volume up, home, on/off button) no I am not.
However I guess I am not getting it well, could you please tell me how to do it ?

Comment: Too long for a comment, but see [hard-reset.com](http://www.hard-reset.com/samsung-galaxy-s4-hard-reset.html). If that works out, I will include the steps in an answer, of course.

Comment: That is what I tried, however it didn't work. Pressing and holding these buttons did not change anything

Comment: OK, then I'm out, an leaving the field for somebody else. Good luck!

Comment: No problem, Hopefully there is some one else could help me

Comment: Sound like you got stuck in an OTA update and ran out of battery. Take it back to the shop for service or replacement. Sorry, this is a lame answer, but I see no reason for a non-expert to have to deal with this Samsung crap, especially for their top-of-the-line devices.